# Storing and updating values on a vb.net windows form

Tags: vb.net

this is my first question here and I hope I explain it correctly.

I am working in VB Studio 2010 and I want to create a simple banking application using a windows form.

I want to store a user profile that houses the following:

First Name
Last Name
Login
Current Balance

I want to allow the user to "login" and add or remove money from there current balance. I then want to update thier balance to reflect the new amount.

Doing the math side is easy for me but I cannot figure out how to store a balance value and be able to update the balance with the new value.

Any assistance you can offer would be very appreciated.

Comment: store the information to a file? is that what you after?

Comment: Create a Class to hold that information, then use a List(Of ThatClassType) to hold the instances of it.  Now use XML Serialization to save it to a file and read it back.  You'll update the file by completely overwriting it with the new data.  This is a simple solution that would work for a **small** number of users.  Is this is a learning exercise or a homework project?...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is a learning exercise for myself. I know if I can accomplish something like this, I would be able to use the functionality within on many other projects.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting place for you might be storing the information in simple text. It's easy to write/read, just use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` in a for-loop and parse your information as a string. Writing, you can use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText`. You can format a text file with keywords to signify different values. I might suggest a format such as:

```
    [User]
    MyName MyLastName
    MyPassword
    $0.02
    [User]
    AnotherName TheirLastName
    TheirPassword
    $0.10
```

Next you might try working with XML. This allows you to store and organize information quickly and easily. You can read it just like any other simple text file. Here's an example of what it could look like. Search for help on the `System.XML` class.

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <FirstName>MyName</FirstName>
    <LastName>MyLastName</LastName>
    <Password>MyPassword</Password>
    <Balance>$0.02</Balance>
  </User>
  <User>
    <FirstName>AnotherName</FirsName>
    <LastName>TheirLastName</LastName>
    <Password>TheirPassword</Password>
    <Balance>$0.10</Balance>
  </User>
</Users>
```

XML Tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/

Then you should look into database programming. ie. MS Access, SQL Compact, MySQL, etc. This method can provide the most security (with regards to the methods above) if setup properly and would be much faster than XML for larger databases. Search for help on classes such as `System.Data.OLEDB` or `System.Data.SQL`

SQL Tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp